# On Ubuntu, a simple script with a disabling function didn't work

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

Okay, so I made a script to simply display a load of information and a link to a get started command (e.g. sh https://website.tld/scripts/getstarted.sh) with the ability to disable it
e.g.

```
commandenabled=false
if [[ commandenabled = false ]]; then
echo "command has been disabled by an administrator"
else
Rest Of Command Here
```

This didn't work for me, even with the other bits for the code.
My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env

# Command Options
headname=unlac.net
commandenabled=true
commandname=ulcwelcome
version=0.0.1
author=ydupc
servername=ulctesting


if [[ $commandenabled = "false" ]]; then
    echo "\e[4m\e[1mErr: ULC-001, Command Disabled.\e[0m"
else
    echo "\e[2m=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=[$headname]=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\e[0m"
fi
```

Does anyone know why it still executes the area after the "else" statement and even when is set to disabled? I got really confused here.

Comment: When evaluating, you'd need a double equal sign `==` ... a single `=` is used to set variables not evaluating ... also get into the habit of quoting your variables inside your script like `"$commandenabled"`

Comment: @Raffa in the context of `[[ expression ]]` extended test brackets *"The ‘=’ operator is identical to ‘==’."* In the context of a POSIX `[ expression ]`, `==` isn't supported at all.

Comment: I can't figure out the problem because of the typos: in the first snippet, you don't have variable expansion; in the second you explicitly have `commandenabled=true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is the script isn't run with Bash.

The *shebang* (first line of your script) is wrong. This should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Then your if-statement is using `[[`, which is a "Bashism" - so I guess the if-statement simply isn't properly evaluated.

I also would guess the if-statement is properly evaluated if you use single square brackets `[`, which is the default Posix if-statement.

Try running the script again with the proper shebang, or with `[ ]` around your evaluation expression in the if-statement.

A good idea would be to always run your script through `shellcheck`, like this:

```
shellcheck <yourscript>
```

It's much better at detecting errors than us humans.

Comment: Returns "[[: not found" when executed.

Comment: Thanks, it was the brackets :)